# Consctruct a list of sublists of N*N elements

Tags: list, integer, ocaml

I'm trying to construct a list in ocaml only using **List.map, List.filters**, and **anonymous functions**

What i want to get is this:

```
- : int list list = [[2; 2]; [5; 5; 5; 5; 5]; [7; 7; 7; 7; 7; 7; 7]; [3; 3; 3];
2
[12; 12; 12; 12; 12; 12; 12; 12; 12; 12; 12; 12]; [4; 4; 4; 4]; ... ]
```

from this list

```
let entiers = [2; 5; 7; 3; 12; 4; 9; 2; 11];;
```

What i've tried so far:

```
List.map (fun n acc -> acc = n if acc = 0 then [] else n :: fun n acc -1 ) entiers;;
```

But i'm getting a syntax error, so i'm kinded of stuck...

Can someone help me to solve this problem ?
Thank you !

Comment: The first `acc = n` is suspicious. Also think of the types. Is `acc` an integer? Also when you do `acc - 1` you need parentheses. Finally, recursive anonymous functions are not impossible, but it's best to forget it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ChristopheRiolo comments, it looks like you're trying to define an anonymous function that is recursive. This is very difficult, as you really need the name of the function for it to call itself recursively.

In particular, it looks like this fragment:

```
fun n (acc - 1)
```

is intended as a recursive call. However, this is not a function call at all but the beginning of definition of a new (inner) anonymous function. (This is the source of the syntax error since it's not a valid lambda definition.)

It will work much better if you define the function to be mapped ouside the call to `map`, as a function with a name.

Something very roughly like this:

```
let rec helper n =
    if n = 0 then [] else n :: helper (n - 1)
in
List.map helper ...
```

(This definition of helper is probably not correct; I'm just trying to show the general layout you might want to use.)

Answer (score 0):

If you were allowed to use `List.init` this becomes trivial.

```
# let f n = List.init n (fun _ -> n);;
val f : int -> int list = <fun>
# f 6;;
- : int list = [6; 6; 6; 6; 6; 6]
# [1; 2; 3; 4] |> List.map f;;
- : int list list = [[1]; [2; 2]; [3; 3; 3]; [4; 4; 4; 4]]
```

So reinvent the wheel by writing your own `list_init` function. Homework that says you can't use library functions doesn't usually specify that you can't reimplement them yourself.

We count *down* because of the way the accumulator list is built up. This way it's not necessary to reverse the accumulator when we're done.

```
# let list_init n f =
    let rec aux i acc =
      if i < 0 then acc
      else aux (i - 1) (f i :: acc)
    in
    aux (n-1) [];;
val list_init : int -> (int -> 'a) -> 'a list = <fun>
# let f n = list_init n (fun _ -> n);;
val f : int -> int list = <fun>
# [1; 2; 3; 4] |> List.map f;;
- : int list list = [[1]; [2; 2]; [3; 3; 3]; [4; 4; 4; 4]]
```